# How to dynamically move a row of button on its line

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to make a game where a row of button can be moved on the sides when clicking a pushbutton.

I use stretcher so far in the layout and can put it in the different states I want it to be, but not dynamically.  The data is updated when I push the button but using update() or repaint() doesnt work at all (I might use them wrong).

```
decal = [0,0,0,0]    #values between -3 and +3, one for each row

class grid(QWidget):
    """
    creates the grid layout by aligning a set of rows
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addStretch()
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        for i in range(4):
            layout.addItem(row(i))
        layout.addStretch()
        self.setLayout(layout)


class row(QHBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, ligne):
        super().__init__()
        self.ligne = ligne
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        # ajout des widgets et stretch
        self.addWidget(rangmoins(self.ligne))
        self.addStretch(3 + decal[self.ligne])
        for i in range(4):
            self.addWidget(gridbutton(self.ligne, i))
        self.addStretch(3 - decal[self.ligne]) # I modify the decal value to move the row and the size of the stretch
        self.addWidget(rangplus(self.ligne))
        self.setSpacing(0)


class rangplus(QPushButton):
    """
    modifies the values of decal to change the stretchitems size
    """
    def __init__(self, ligne):
        super().__init__()
        self.side = 52
        self.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        self.ligne = ligne
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setFixedSize(self.side, self.side)
        self.setText(">")

    def on_click(self):
        global joueur
        if decal[self.ligne] != 3:
            joueur = joueur % 2 + 1
            decal[self.ligne] += 1
            window.repaint() # need to update the window so it displays the change
        else:
            print("coup impossible")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to provide the answer tailored to your code because not all the variables are defined in the snippet you provided. But here is a general way to achieve this with QGridLayout. What you do is remove each button in the row, replace it with a QSpacerItem, and insert the button in a new column on the other side. Try running this example, and see if you can adapt it to your code:

```
class Template(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.grid = QGridLayout(self)
        self.grid.setHorizontalSpacing(0)
        for row in range(4):
            for col in range(4):
                self.grid.addWidget(QPushButton(str(row)), row, col)

        for i in range(4):
            btn = QPushButton('>')
            btn.clicked.connect(self.move_buttons)
            self.grid.addWidget(btn, i, 4)

    def move_buttons(self):
        row = self.grid.getItemPosition(self.grid.indexOf(self.sender()))[0]
        for col in range(4):
            btn = self.grid.itemAtPosition(row, col).widget()
            self.grid.removeWidget(btn)
            self.grid.addWidget(btn, row, col + 5)
            self.grid.addItem(QSpacerItem(btn.width(), btn.height(), QSizePolicy.Maximum, QSizePolicy.Maximum), row, col)
```